# Access YouTube API Response Data with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get specific data from the YouTube API. useEffect fetches the data from videos from a specific playlist and returns the information to YTData using useState. I can see the response in Chromes console, but I am not able to access specific data. When I console.log(YTData), I say a list of videos within an array. But when

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Home.css'
//Components
import Header from '../../Components/Header/Header';
import Footer from '../../Components/Footer/Footer';
//Repositories
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';


const Home = () => {
    const YouTube_Playlist_Items_API = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_PlayList_Item_API_URL;
    const YouTube_Key = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_API_KEY;
    const YouTube_Playlist_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_PlayList_Item_ID;
    const YouTube_MaxResults = process.env.REACT_APP_YouTube_PlayList_Max_Results;

    const [YTData, setYTData] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (YTData){
            return;
        }
        getServerSideProps();
    }, []);

    // declare the async data fetching function
    const getServerSideProps = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        // get the data from the api
        fetch(`${YouTube_Playlist_Items_API}?part=snippet&playlistId=${YouTube_Playlist_ID}&maxResults=${YouTube_MaxResults}&key=${YouTube_Key}`)
        // convert data to json
        .then((res) =>  res.json())
        .then((data) => {setYTData(data.items)
        setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            setIsLoading(false);
        })
    }

    console.log('YTData', YTData);

    return (
        <>
            {
                isLoading ?
                    (<>
                        <Header />
                        <div className='homeBody'>
                            <h1>Loading...</h1>
                        </div>
                        <Footer />
                    </>)
                    :
                    (<>
                        <Header />
                        <div className='homeBody'>
                            <p>Hello</p>
                        </div>
                        <Footer />
                    </>)
            }
        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Results from console.log('YTData', YTData);

[image: Results from console.log('YTData', YTData);]

Results from console.log('YTData', YTData.items);

[image: Results from console.log('YTData', YTData.items);]

Comment: `YTData` is a **array** not a **object** so the property `items` does not exits. You can use some kind of loop to list the items of your state (YTData)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you’re saying to make a loop and loop through YTData? If possible, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YTData** is not an object so, you can't find the items property anywhere.
I'm thinking you wanted to load these objects on the interface.

First of all, change this

```
const [YTData, setYTData] = useState(null);
```

to

```
const [YTData, setYTData] = useState([]);
```

Then change the return block to

```
return (
    <>
        <Header />
            <div className="homeBody">
                {isLoading ? <h1>Loading...</h1> : YTData.map((obj) => <p>{obj.etag}</p>)}
            </div>
        <Footer />
    </>
);
```

Comment: I get YTData.map is not a function when I change the return block.

Comment: Did you change the first part? Because you initially had null as the value for YTData .
Please change that first.

Comment: I did change the first part but its saying there's an issue with .map

Comment: I also have one warning in the VSCode terminal, which is Line 38:8:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getServerSideProps'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: You must be doing something the wrong way. Is this a next app? Did you reload the app, if everything has been places in the correct position, this code should run just fine.

Comment: It is a ReactJS app, I am only getting an error for .map.

Comment: Please update your post and include the latest code

Comment: It is towards the bottom of the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253437/discussion-between-peter-and-jond).

Comment: I had to change setYTData(data); back to setYTData(data.items); and that resolved the issue as you said. Thank you so much!